# Prime factorization in pascal as a function/procedure

Tags: arrays, pascal, dynamic-arrays, freepascal, prime-factoring

I have to build a prime factorization program with pascal using a function or procedure.
I think I am on a pretty good path, but my problem at the moment is, that it seems to be impossible to assign a dynamic relay as the ouput of a function/procedure. And I have no real clue what I could use or do instead (except a string, but that feels just not right at all).

```
PROCEDURE PrimFac(n: INTEGER; VAR res: array of INTEGER);

VAR
    divisor, a, counter: INTEGER;
    b: array of INTEGER;

BEGIN
    divisor := 2;
    a := n;
    counter := 0;
    WHILE divisor <= n DIV 2 DO BEGIN
        IF a MOD divisor = 0 THEN BEGIN
            a := a DIV divisor;
            counter := counter + 1;
            SetLength(b, counter);
            b[counter] := divisor;
        END
        ELSE
            divisor := divisor + 1;
    END;
    res := b
END;

BEGIN
WriteLn(PrimFac(210));
END.
```

Any help or hint would be highly appreciated. (:
Thank you very much in advance
-Florian

Comment: When you pass an array as a VAR parameter, the intention is that you modify that same array `res`, rather than assign to it.

Comment: So you mean I could get completely rid of "b"? I think that makes sense and to be honest "b" is just a remnant of my try to build it as a function. But even without the "b", the problem with the dynamic array persists...

Comment: If your Pascal compiler doesn't allow resizing arrays dynamically, you can put your results in a singly linked list and return a pointer to the first element of it. Since you would allocate the elements of the list from the heap rather than from the stack, they will not disappear as you return from your function, as would a local array. Example of a singly linked list at: http://www.baskent.edu.tr/~tkaracay/etudio/ders/prg/pascal/PasHTM3/pas/pasl3005.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this is FreePascal, which is quite similar to Delphi.

Instead of using an [*open array parameter*](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html) (which should not be confused with a *dynamic array*, despite the similar syntax), you should pre-define a type to return:

```
type
  TIntegerDynArray = array of Integer;

function PrimFac(n: Integer): TIntegerDynArray;
...
  SetLength(Result, counter);
  Result[counter - 1] := divisor;
...
```

FWIW, reallocating a dynamic array each time you want to add an element is generally not a good idea. Better to keep the results in a temporary `TList` (if possible, a generic `TList`) and then, at the end, to turn that into an array of the desired length, and then to get rid of the temporary list again, IOW something like (untested):

```
uses
  fgl;

type
  TIntegerDynArray = array of Integer;
  TIntegerList = specialize TFPGList<Integer>;

function PrimFac(N: Integer): TIntegerDynArray;
var
  Divisor, A, I: Integer;
  L: TIntegerList; 
begin
  A := N;
  L := TIntegerList.Create;
  try
    { Find divisors and add each to list. }
    for Divisor := 2 to N div 2 do
    begin
      { Use "while" so a divisor can be found multiple times, e.g. }
      { using "if": 1000 --> 2 4 5 25 (but 4 = 2*2, and 25 = 5*5)  }
      { using "while": 1000 --> 2 2 2 5 5 5                        }
      while A mod Divisor = 0 do
      begin
        A := A div Divisor;
        L.Add(Divisor);
      end;
    end;

    { Copy list to result array. }
    SetLength(Result, L.Count);
    for I := 0 to L.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Result[I] := L[I];
    end;
  finally
    L.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note that your algorithm could do with a few extra checks (for 0, for 1, etc.), but that is up to you. I merely answered how to return the values.

### Update

If you want to print the list, then do something like:

```
    { Find divisors and print each one. }
    for Divisor := 2 to N div 2 do
    begin
      while A mod Divisor = 0 do
      begin
        A := A div Divisor;
        L.Add(Divisor);
        Write(Divisor, ' ');
      end;
    end;
    Writeln;
```

This lists all numbers separated by spaces and performs a final newline when it is finished. If you want more sophisticated output, use your imagination.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot already.

The first solution you offered seems to work just fine, but now I am unable to write my array to the console ):

Is it really impossible in pascal to just write all values of an array at once? And if I am forced to use a loop, how can I get that into a function? As far as I understand, I have to have exactly one output in a function...

I also tried your second solution but unfortunately my compiler does not know `TList` I am always getting `Error: Identifier not found "TList"` as an error.

Comment: You can of course write values to an array directly, but then you should know the size of the array beforehand, which you don't. You can also increment the size each time you add an element, but that can get very slow. So, to avoid performance hits, you'll have to increment the size of the array  in chunks, and keep track of the actual number of items in the array. Well, that is exactly what TList does already, so why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not explain my issue well enough. My problem now is, that I want to print all integers of the array at once. e. g. `array := array of Integer;` `WriteLn(array)` but that does not work (for me). So my question was, if there is any possibility to do that, or if I have to use a loop. The problem I do have with a loop is, that I have no clue, how I could integrate that into my function/a new function.
Concerning the reinvention of the wheel you are absolutely right. Unfortunately this is university stuff and there you are often forced to reinvent the wheel with the argument...

Comment: ... of learning the basics. So I am a little bit of handcuffed there and need to find a way to output all values of my array to console.

Comment: You can't `Write(someArray);`. You will have to use a loop, either `var I: Integer; begin for I in theArray do Writeln(I); end;` or `var I: Integer; begin for I := 0 to High(theArray) do Writeln(theArray[I]); end;`.